# Querying WHERE = Multiple Possible Values

Tags: soql

I'm sure that this will have been asked before because all I'm trying to do here is replicate the standard report filter functionality. But I can't find the question so apologies in advance..

I need to retrieve a list of `Opportunities` whose `Lead Source` field contains any of a long list of possible values. In a report that filter would look like `Lead Source` *Equals* `Phone,Website,Email`.

Unfortunately this is an 'isolated' SOQL query that's being used in a 3rd party reporting tool (Klipfolio) so I don't have the ability to build a Set of potential values & use an IN clause in my query i.e.

```
Set<String> leadSources = new Set<String>('Phone','Website','Email');

SELECT Id
  FROM Opportunity
 WHERE LeadSource IN :leadsources
```

Is it possible to list the various values without having to use `AND (LeadSource = 'value1' OR LeadSource = 'value2' OR [etc.])`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **can** still use the `IN` clause.

For example:

```
[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE LeadSource IN ('Phone', 'Email', 'Website')];
```

This is useful when you're querying, say, a picklist with specific values you want to hard-code. Using a Set creates a collection which could then be modified depending on, for example, a search the User is conducting.

But, `WHERE Id IN :mySet` just uses a bind variable which effectively rerenders to `WHERE Id IN ([...])`.

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm?search_text=WHERE):

> If the value equals any one of the specified values in a WHERE clause. For example:
>
> `SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE BillingState IN ('California', 'New York')`
>
> The values for IN must be in parentheses. String values must be surrounded by single quotes.
>
> IN and NOT IN can also be used for semi-joins and anti-joins when querying on ID (primary key) or reference (foreign key) fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, that's worked. I'll accept your answer as soon as the site lets me.

Comment: You're welcome @AlexS. I updated it with a bit more info and provided a link to the docs which should be a useful resource. I have to admit when I first Googled the `IN` clause, it did take a bit of searching to find them. I guess "in" isn't a very helpful word. :)

Comment: Indeed this approach works well. Note that it doesn't work with `LIKE`, however.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've managed to get Sets to work with the `LIKE` operator, if it can be called that. Something akin to `WHERE LeadSource LIKE ('%Phone%', '%Email%', '%Website%')`. I don't know how efficient this is though. Of course I had to loop through each value to append and prepend the value with a percentage sign.

Comment: I thought it didn't work when merged into the query without a separately defined collection.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ah that's where you're probably right then as I was using collections to achieve that.